# mac ld: library not found for -lm

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to install [marty](https://github.com/docbrown1955/marty-public) on my mac. When running `sudo make` I get the error `library not found for -lm`. Googling for a solution does not yield great results... Any suggestion?

Comment: Why sudo, you shouldn't build as root, at worst the install part

Comment: If you followed the build instructions and it doesn't work, contact the developers. That will be more effective.

Comment: We'll probably need more information from you about your environment.  What C compilation subsystem (for example, which version of Xcode) are you using, and how did you install it?  I compile C on my Mac all the time, and I don't have problems with `-lm`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install marty in **/usr/local**. Follow README.md instruction for installation.
If you are still not able to install it in your system them open a new issue describing the bug.